# angular2 searching into view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-template

I have a Component for tree view. If if tried use ViewChilden to search elems, result is 0.

template:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="levels-list-item" *ngFor="let level of levelsList">
        <div class="flex justify-flex-start dropdown-item align-center">
            <i class="wrapper fa fa-play rotate-90"
               [ngClass]="{'invisible': !  level.childs?.length}"
               attr.data-id="{{level.id}}"
               #dropdownTrigger></i>
            <div class="dropdown-item-inner flex full-width align-center">
                <div class="name">{{level.title}}</div>
                <div class="tools flex justify-flex-start">
                    <a class="wrapper tool" title="Добавить уровень"
                       [routerLink]="['../LevelAdd', {parentId: level.parentId}]"
                       *ngIf="isPDO(level.type)">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="tool wrapper" title="Редактировать уровень"
                       [routerLink]="['../LevelEdit', {parentId: level.parentId, id: level.id}]">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <levels-list-item [childs]="level.childs"></levels-list-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In class i use:

```
@ViewChildren("dropdownTrigger") dropdownTriggerElms: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Elems were find only in childrens.

Other component called it by using this

```
<levels-list-item [childs]="list | async"></levels-list-item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `@ViewChildren()` (`dropdownTriggerElms`) is only set in or after `ngAfterViewInit()`. If you try to access it from the `constructor` it will be `null`.

For changes that happen later use `dropdownTriggerElms.changes.subscribe(...)`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dropdownTriggerElms.changes.subscribe(value => console.log('changes', value));
}
```

Comment: I know it but it's not helping

Comment: Its not null, Query length is 0

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else, but hard to tell without seeing the code. Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Maybe array levelsList is loaded later?

Comment: If `levelsList` is initialized async it probably arrives only after `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried, but it did not work very well
https://plnkr.co/edit/L5Xds8afliIFjiKeQ1IH

Comment: The plunker is now working but the component fails. Maybe you can improve it from that state https://plnkr.co/edit/qPDiM6eYk3wj13iR68jF?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 
https://plnkr.co/edit/L5Xds8afliIFjiKeQ1IH?p=preview

But it's working here

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, other component called it by using <levels-list-item [child's]="list | async"></levels-list-item>

Comment: Can you try in your local code to add `this.dropdownTriggerElms.changes.subscribe(value => console.log('changes', value));` to `ngAfterViewInit()` if this changes the output?